# Double assigned shortcut key when using firefox

Tags: support, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

In Firefox, I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to jump to the URL box.

When I am in the edit post box on Stack Exchange sites, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> creates a link in the edit box, instead of jumping to the URL box.

I don't want to change the key settings in either firefox or in Stack Exchange editing box.

I wonder if I can add some escape modifier key before ctrl+L to jump to Firefox URL box in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Use <kbd>F6</kbd> to go to the URL box. Or press Tab (to go to the [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) box) and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> may work?

Comment: thanks. can you explain why it may work?

Comment: @Tim Becasue the Ctrl+L doesn't do anything in the Tags area. And F6 always works.